# Showing database events in fullcalendar

Tags: php, mysql, fullcalendar

I have a list of events in my database and i would like to show it on the calendar in my application. Below is the js function i used to create calendar. Is there any way to show my database events in it??

```
        function  init_calendar() {

            if( typeof ($.fn.fullCalendar) === 'undefined'){ return; }
            console.log('init_calendar');

            var date = new Date(),
                d = date.getDate(),
                m = date.getMonth(),
                y = date.getFullYear(),
                started,
                categoryClass;

            var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
              header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listMonth'
              },
              selectable: true,
              selectHelper: true,
              select: function(start, end, allDay) {
                $('#fc_create').click();

                started = start;
                ended = end;

                $(".antosubmit").on("click", function() {
                  var title = $("#title").val();
                  if (end) {
                    ended = end;
                  }

                  categoryClass = $("#event_type").val();

                  if (title) {
                    calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent', {
                        title: title,
                        start: started,
                        end: end,
                        allDay: allDay
                      },
                      true // make the event "stick"
                    );
                  }

                  $('#title').val('');

                  calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');

                  $('.antoclose').click();

                  return false;
                });
              },
              eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
                $('#fc_edit').click();
                $('#title2').val(calEvent.title);

                categoryClass = $("#event_type").val();

                $(".antosubmit2").on("click", function() {
                  calEvent.title = $("#title2").val();

                  calendar.fullCalendar('updateEvent', calEvent);
                  $('.antoclose2').click();
                });

                calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
              },
              editable: true,
              events: [{
                title: 'All Day Event',
                start: new Date(y, m, 1)
              }, {
                title: 'Long Event',
                start: new Date(y, m, d - 5),
                end: new Date(y, m, d - 2)
              }, {
                title: 'Meeting',
                start: new Date(y, m, d, 10, 30),
                allDay: false
              }, {
                title: 'Lunch',
                start: new Date(y, m, d + 14, 12, 0),
                end: new Date(y, m, d, 14, 0),
                allDay: false
              }, {
                title: 'Birthday Party',
                start: new Date(y, m, d + 1, 19, 0),
                end: new Date(y, m, d + 1, 22, 30),
                allDay: false
              }, {
                title: 'Click for Google',
                start: new Date(y, m, 28),
                end: new Date(y, m, 29),
                url: 'http://google.com/'
              }]
            });

        };
```

Comment: Implement as per https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/ or https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_function/. Basically you populate the events via ajax from your webserver, which in turn can read them from your database.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use fullCalendar's [events](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/) option to specify events source.